# Show that $\frac{d}{dx}f(0,0)$ exists

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Define $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ by $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, \text{ $x,y \neq (0,0)$ }, \\ 0, \text{ $(x,y)=(0,0)$}\end{cases}$$

Show that $\frac{d}{dx}f(0,0)$ exists. (it's supposed to be just a computation)

I'm not sure how to do this. What i've tried:

$$f_x(0,0)$=\frac{(xy)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-xy\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)'}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{y\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-xy\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{y^3}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(x^2+y^2)}=\frac{(xy)^3}{x^3\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^3}=\frac{(f(0,0))^3}{x^3}=0
$$

Would this be correct? I can't think of anything else. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please check the definition of partial derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. By definition $f_x(0,0)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(h,0)-f(0,0)}h$. And $f(h,0)-f(0,0)=0-0=0$ for all $h \neq 0$. Hence the limit is $0$.

Comment: why is $f(h,0)=0$?

Comment: What happens when you put $y=0$ in the definition of $f(x,y)$?

Comment: @Marina just plug it in and you'll see why.